# Place two arrows on each side of a div AND make it responsive

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm getting really frustrated with an issue I have. I have a picture carousel on my app, and I'm trying to get two arrows on either side of that picture. My entire page layout is made using flexbox, but it seems that I can't use flexbox to achieve the result I want. I've seen other people post similar questions, and everyone's solution is to use `position: absolute`. The problem I have with this is that it's not responsive at all. I'm working with a mobile-first design, so as soon as the width increases even a tiny bit, the position of the arrows gets messed up. I would have to have 50 media queries to make it responsive.

Here's my code (made in React):

```
<div className="dashboard">

   <div className="left-right-btn">
     <div className='left_button'>
     <button className="left-btn btn" onClick={this.prevPicture}>{'<'} 
 </button>
     </div>

     <div className='right_button'>
     <button className="right-btn btn" onClick={this.nextPicture}>{'>'} 
 </button>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div className="dashboard-pic">
     <div className="picture-name">{userName}</div>

     <div className="picture-carousel">    
        <Link to={`/profile/${userId}`}><img src={userPic} alt=''/></Link>
     </div>

     <div className='eventify_link_button'>
        {this.renderEventifyButton()}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
.dashboard {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.dashboard-pic {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.picture-carousel {
    min-width:L 0;
    margin: 5px;
}

.picture-carousel img {
   width:300px;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 300px
}

.left-right-btn {
    position: relative;
}

.left_button {
    position: absolute;
    left: -140px;
    top: 14em;
}

.right_button{
    position: absolute;
    right: -140px;
    top: 14em;
}
```

This is how it looks right now (with `position: absolute`) in mobile view. I want it to look like this no matter the width

[image: picture with arrows on each side]

Comment: Why `flex-direction:column` on the `.dashboard` div? Can we change the HTML?

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, we can change the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox on the `.dashboard` div with the default direction of `row` and adjust the HTML to take advantage of the flow.

```css
.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="left_button">
    <button class="left-btn btn">Prev</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard-pic">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right_button">
    <button class="right-btn btn">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="left_button">
    <button class="left-btn btn">Prev</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard-pic">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right_button">
    <button class="right-btn btn">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thank you this worked perfectly! I think I was getting a lot of my divs confused and once I rearranged them this worked.